# Is there any way to find the color of a pixel in JavaScript WITHOUT using getImageData()?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

I'm making a small online multiplayer game with JavaScript and the native Canvas API (2d context). I want to find the color of pixels on the screen as a form of collision detection, I figure it'd save resources to not have to process every shape every frame, but rather to simply check if the color of a pixel at a certain position is such that it is contacting a shape. (I hope that makes sense)

I ran some tests and I have an average frame delay of about 4-5 milliseconds without collision detection, and then when I make a single call to my canvas context's `.getImageData()` method, suddenly that frame delay shoots up to 19-20 milliseconds...

As far as I can find online `getImageData()` is the only means of checking the color of a given pixel, but I have to think there's some other way that doesn't introduce such a huge amount of lag.

I tried running `getImageData()` on a small section of the screen vs larger sections, and a 1x1 pixel request introduces 10ms latency, where a 600x600 pixel request is about 15ms... So the issue isn't the amount/size of the request, but rather just the request itself is extremely slow, so there's no potential for optimization here, I NEED another way.

Also, caching the image data is also not an option. I need to poll these pixels every single frame. I can't cache it because the player and the object it needs to collide with are all constantly moving, and they're being controlled over the internet so there's also no way of predicting where they'll be at any given time.

To be clear, I'm not asking how to write collisions or how to make pixel-perfect collision detection systems. I'm asking only how to get the color of a pixel on the canvas without having to use `.toImageData()` because `.toImageData()` is far too slow for my use case.

Comment: Your premise is wrong: checking the color of a pixel is gonna be slower than the worst collision detection you can think of.  Also you say that you are using a webgl context, but this doesn't have a getImageData method, only 2d context does.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, my bad then. I was under the impression that the 2D context was just a layer on top of WebGL? It still uses WebGL, no? Also, how can you be sure that checking the color of a pixel is going to be slower than collision detection? In my use case I have about 200 arcs/lines on the screen (with new ones being added about 5-6 times a second)... Do you really think checking collisions against thousands of arcs every frame is going to be faster than getting the color of a single pixel?

Comment: No it's not on top of WebGL. The 2D context ***may*** be hardware accelerated and thus make use of the GPU as WebGL does, but these are still completely separate APIs. And yes, I'm sure it will be slower, precisely because the 2D context may be hardware accelerated. To read the pixel data the browser has to deaccelerate the context and move the buffer from the GPU to the CPU. This is not only slow when done, it will even slow all the following drawing operations. On the other hand, calculating intersection is only arithmetic, that modern CPUs can do without issues.

Comment: Thank you! That still doesn't answer my question, but it's helpful information and it can help guide me to a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Standard collision detection may end up being a better option. Pixel-perfect checking works well for perfect collision detection with complex objects but can get expensive with lots of pixels.

What I would probably recommend instead is to use standard collision detection with simple shapes. If done right, it should have good performance, even for a more complex game.

If you really do want to use pixel-perfect collision, you'll want to check the rectangular bounding boxes of the two objects first to ensure they aren't far away from each other. If their bounding boxes intersect, you could then use bitmasks of your sprites to quickly check each pixel for overlap. [This question has a bit more info. It's not JS, but the concept would be the same](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/per-pixel-based-collision-detection).